# Understand NodeJS memory

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks

We got a Nodejs app running in production with a memory leak issue.

I'm struggling understanding how nodejs memory works.

I've got this message:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1:0x69e3660] 45788793 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 716.8 (728.9) -> 716.8 (728.9) MB, 610.99 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.474, current mu = 0.000) last resort; GC in old space requested
[1:0x69e3660] 45789396 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 716.8 (728.9) -> 716.8 (728.9) MB, 602.47 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.305, current mu = 0.001) last resort; GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

If I understand correctly, Node don't succeed to allocated memory for old space.

I run node JS with : `--max-heap-size=768`.
But, when I print the memory I got this:
[image]

You can see that the heap used seems quite stable. And that the leak is in the external memory and not in the right. So why the GC is blocked acquiring ?